# Column taking up more pixels than allowed

Tags: html, css

I have this table that should have it's  and  elements to be the same width, but I get this instead [LINK TO IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ogrxf.png). If I set the width element of  it starts to wrap, but for now it is just taking up more space in the table and pushing the other elements out of position. How can I fix this so that all TH and TD elements are the same width? The table layout is fixed.

Comment: You should include your code (probably just `css` and `html` in this case).

Comment: Values inside Seq. ID are too long and without spaces, which is probably the issue. I'm afraid you have to use word-break: break-all

Comment: Yes Ilya, that did it! Thanks! Didn't know that existed :P

Answer (score 0):

If you want the cells to resize depending on the content, then you must not specify a width to the table, the rows, or the cells.

If you don't want word wrap, assign the CSS style white-space: nowrap to the cells.

Comment: Is there a way to make all columns the same width, say, 100 px, regardless of what is inside of them

Answer (score 0):

A little CSS is needed for your TD elements to get cut off correctly.  The trick is adding the "overflow:hidden" to hide anything longer than the width in your css.

```html
<style>
td {
    width: 94px;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: inline-block;
}
</style>

<table width="300" border="1">
 <tr>
  <td width="100">abcderfrjdbgrgoeberov</td>
  <td  width="100">fghf</td>
  <td  width="100">ghgfgf</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>fghfghf</td>
  <td>tghrthtrhtrhtrhtrhtrhtrhrthrth</td>
  <td>ghrthrttrhrt</td>
 </tr>
</table>
```